# Android studio не видит телефон ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

Настроил по этой [инструкции](http://www.rebelcode.ru/android/podklyuchenie-realnyx-android-ustrojstv-v-android-studio-i-eclipse/), телефон настроен правильно, пользовался им на win7. Но когда прописываю в манифесте `android:debuggable="true"`, подчёркивает эту строку красным, а когда открываю `Android monitor`, то пишет:

```
Unable to detect adb version, adb output: /home/alexeyy/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1: /home/alexeyy/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

И телефон `android studio` не видит. Телефон пробовал подключать как камера и как мультимедиа устройство. Система 32-битная `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS`. Видел старые вопросы с похожей проблемой, там рекомендовали скачать пакет `platform-tools` для 32-битной системы, но там старые версии `platform-tools`, последнюю версию я не нашёл.

Вывод на dmesg:

```
[16596.242564] cdc_acm 1-1:1.1: failed to set dtr/rts
[16611.708066] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[16611.857278] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
[16611.857284] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[16611.857288] usb 1-1: Product: GT-I9082
[16611.857292] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: samsung
[16611.857296] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 41006eaed35ab000
[16611.860688] cdc_acm 1-1:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[16611.861802] cdc_acm 1-1:1.3: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
```

Comment: Решил проблему сносом системы и установкой 64-битной версии `ubuntu`. Даже не пришлось настраивать по инструкции выше, всё само заработало, андроид студия видит телефон, приложения ставятся на телефон без проблем:)